# In shell scripting how to use read in echo

Tags: shell-script

```
echo "my name is=`read` and am from `read`"
```

expected output:

```
my name is=sudhir and am from india
```

values `sudhir` and `india` are use inputs.

How to achieve this, I like apply this in 480 questions. dont know number of user inputs required for each question.    please help.

Answer (score 6):

`read` by default reads words from its input *into variables*.

`` `cmd` ``, the ancient form of `$(...)` captures the *output* of a command. By default, `read` doesn't produce any output. The text you see when you type something to be read by `read` is the *echo* of the terminal device, it's not output by `read`¹.

Some `read` implementations can output what they read. For instance, `zsh`'s `read` builtin can do that with `-e` or `-E` (the latter to also store the input in variables in addition to echoing it back).

So in `zsh`:

```
echo "my name is=$(read -e) and am from $(read -e)"
```

Portably, you can read a line of input (as opposed to [the special reading behaviour of `read`](/q/209123)) and output it back with `head -n1`. However note that if standard input is not a terminal device or a seekable file, most `head` implementations would read more than one line.

Many systems also still have a `line` command for that (used to be standard, later deprecated).

```
echo "my name is=$(line) and am from $(line)"
```

Which should read one byte at a time, so not read more than one line of input.

If not available, you can always emulate that `line` with `read`:

```
line() {
  IFS= read -r line
  ret=$?
  printf '%s\n' "$line" || return "$ret"
}
```

Or even make it a

```
prompt() {
  printf >&2 %s "$1"
  IFS= read -r answer
  printf '%s\n' "$answer"
}

printf '%s\n' "my name is=$(
  prompt "What is your name? ") and am from $(
  prompt "Where are you from? ")"
```

(here using `printf` instead of `echo` as [`echo` can generally not be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803)).

(same as `zsh`'s `IFS= read -re '?What is your name? '`).

For completeness, with `csh` or `tcsh`, you can do:

```
printf '%s\n' "my name is=$< and am from $<"
```

`$<` being csh's way to read input into a variable.

If you wanted to repeat that for every two lines of input, it would be better to use a text processing utility like `awk`:

```
awk '{name=$0; getline place; print "my name is="name" and am from "place}'
```

---

¹ unless `read` is configured to implement a line editor by itself like with `read -e` in `bash` or by setting the `emacs`, `gmacs` or `vi` option in `ksh93` (and stdin is a terminal device), but then `read` would output the *echo* on stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Please give command here for my comment so that I can add in my script.

Comment: Note:  I have to apply this for 480 entries so dont give suggest specific to only example I mentioned.         Say another entry is                                                 echo "Value of A is `read` and Value of C is `read`----`read` and value of D is `read` End"        here o/p should be "Value of A is (value need to enter for display of preceding string) and Value of C is (value need to enter for display of preceding string)----(value need to enter for display of preceding string) and value of D is |

Comment: @sudhirtataraju, not sure what you mean. See if the edit helps. Please edit your question to add clarifications.

Comment: Hi Stephane,   Thank you so much, after seeing your answer only I have come to know that csh, tcsh & zsh exist.      in your suggestion    awk '{name=$0; getline place; print "my name is="name" and am from "place}'   is asking values 1st to enter , if i enter 2 values then i is displaying output with string "my name is"                  but how am expecting is   1st it should print                "my name is" then it should allow to enter value followed by next static sting allowing another input to enter.                     this I o/p I have to redirect to another file

Comment: echo "my name is=";read a;echo "and am from";read a  ----------- This command working but when i run ---------"read a"  coming in next line and after entering "and am from" printing in third line -----------I want all to be asked in same line and I want to redirect the o/p to a file in one retry ---                     i.e something like   ----------         echo "my name is='read a' and am from 'read b' " > output.txt ---------              after running this in output.txt-------       i should see        
   ------->  my name is sudhir and am from hyd